# Which is a valid/invalid question for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

Stack Overflow's FAQ has the details regarding, what questions could be asked. But I have seen a couple of instances where people have asked non programming questions but still have gotten lots of upvotes for the questions.

**Check out this:** [How to pick an open source project to join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532352/how-to-pick-an-open-source-project-to-join)

While my question, which is actually a technical question, was closed by the moderators as **Not a real question**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523418/how-to-design-similar-app-like-google-mail-the-story-of-send

If anyone encounters some interesting apps/tools & will try to develop similar ones, then they can obviously ask it to the community. After that only they can explore, then implement, and if face problem then ask here. Right?

So anyone can explain me why the 1st one is valid and 2nd is invalid for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Look at the date of that first question. It's an old question from when the site just started. Different times, different rules. The site has moved on. But you're right in saying that that question would now no longer be appropriate. It has now been closed.

Comment: @Bart: Yeah, you are right. But can you suggest which is the right place to ask?

Comment: The question you're asking would not be appropriate on any site within the network that I'm aware of. It's both too vague and too broad.

Comment: @Bart: Ohh then itz too bad. Actually I tried a lot to design a similar app like The Story of send from Google but couldnot get a single clue. unknowingly I asked it in SO & the response helped me a lot which is the 2nd link above. So there is absolutely no Stack Exchange community for discussing/sharing programming ideas?

Comment: Not really no. It's simply not what the sites were meant to do. That's also why they don't really provide the functionality to do so.

Answer (score 4):

> So anyone can explain me why the 1st one is valid and 2nd is invalid for Stack Overflow?

Stack Overflow had slightly different rules back in 2009 and the acceptableness of a question/answer was way more relaxed. The first one has now been closed as *not constructive* and shouldn't be considered *valid* anymore.

> While my question, which is actually a technical question, was closed by the moderators as Not a real question: How to design similar app like Google Mail - The story of send?

Quoting the FAQ, you should ask questions about specific and pratical programming problems (algorithms, errors etc...). Your question is very broad an not suitable to any website in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: So there is absolutely no Stack Exchange community for discussing/sharing programming ideas? If any such community is there, then it would definitely help others to start with new Apps. Isn't it?

Comment: @skumar, it's against the Stack Exchange network philosophy of accepting pratical and answerable questions only. I'm sure you'll find other communities outside though.